# How to perform background task with jQuery promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I have a long synchronous function and I would like to promisify it with jQuery.when and/or jQuery.Deferred().

I'm struggling and don't find any example!

Example (typescript):

```
public Bind(cell: number) {
    console.log("entering!");
    $.when(this.validateCell(cell)).done( () => {
        console.log("finished!");
    });
    console.log("out!");
}

private validateCell(cell: number): JQueryPromise<any> {
    const dfd = $.Deferred();
    console.log("0");
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        const t = i;
    }
    console.log("1");
    dfd.resolve();
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

I get this:

```
entering!
0
1
finished!
out!
```

While I would like to get this:

```
entering!
out!
0
1
finished!
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't take a long sync task and make it async - JS doesn't do that.  The only exception I know of is if you split that task out into a `WebWorker`.

Comment: If your function takes a long time, because it has too many calculations, you wont get any benefit from using promisses. Promisses only help, if you have to wait for some asynchronous operation (ajax, etc).

Answer (score 0):

> How to perform background task with jQuery promise?

You can't. Using a promise doesn't change what thread the work is done on, only (potentially) *when* it's done.

If you want it to run in the background, you'll need to offload it to a web worker ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)).

Answer (score -2):

try to add `setTimeout`

```
 private validateCell(cell: number): JQueryPromise<any> {
        const dfd = $.Deferred();
        console.log("0");
        setTimeout(function(){
           for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
               const t = i;
           }
         })
        console.log("1");
        dfd.resolve();
        return dfd.promise();
    }
```

Comment: This won't work.   Not only will it still cause the long task to happen on the main thread (blocking the UI while it runs) it'll also resolve the promise immediately without waiting for that task.